# Replace second space for \n if applies in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a vector of text, lets say:

```
vector <- c("20 DE NOVIEMBRE",  "CENTRO", "EL ARENAL 4A SECCION",     "IGNACIO ZARAGOZA", "JARDIN BALBUENA", "MOCTEZUMA 2A SECCION",    "MORELOS", "PEON DE LOS BAOS")
```

I want to substitute second space, if exists, with the special character "\n".

I've tried this:

```
  vector <- gsub(".* .*( ).*", "\\\n", vector)
```

But didn't work.

This is the expected result:

```
c("20 DE\nNOVIEMBRE",  "CENTRO", "EL ARENAL\n4A SECCION",     "IGNACIO ZARAGOZA", "JARDIN BALBUENA", "MOCTEZUMA 2A\nSECCION",    "MORELOS", "PEON DE\nLOS BAOS")
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach, using `sub` with capture groups:

```
vector <- sub("^(\\S+) (\\S+) ", "\\1 \\2\n", vector)
vector

[1] "20 DE\nNOVIEMBRE"      "CENTRO"                "EL ARENAL\n4A SECCION"
[4] "IGNACIO ZARAGOZA"      "JARDIN BALBUENA"       "MOCTEZUMA 2A\nSECCION"
[7] "MORELOS"               "PEON DE\nLOS BAOS"
```

**Data:**

```
vector <- c("20 DE NOVIEMBRE",  "CENTRO", "EL ARENAL 4A SECCION",
            "IGNACIO ZARAGOZA", "JARDIN BALBUENA", "MOCTEZUMA 2A SECCION",
            "MORELOS", "PEON DE LOS BAOS")
```

The regex logic here simply says to capture the first and second words, given by `\S+`, consuming the first and second space as well.  Note that this would only match should the input in fact have a second space.  Then, we replace with the same, but substituting a `\n` line feed in place of the second space.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
vector <- c("20 DE NOVIEMBRE",  "CENTRO", "EL ARENAL 4A SECCION",     "IGNACIO ZARAGOZA", "JARDIN BALBUENA", "MOCTEZUMA 2A SECCION",    "MORELOS", "PEON DE LOS BAOS")
sub("^\\S+\\s+\\S+\\K\\s+", "\n", vector, perl=TRUE)
```

Output of the [R demo](https://ideone.com/ww8H5r):

```
[1] "20 DE\nNOVIEMBRE"      "CENTRO"                "EL ARENAL\n4A SECCION"
[4] "IGNACIO ZARAGOZA"      "JARDIN BALBUENA"       "MOCTEZUMA 2A\nSECCION"
[7] "MORELOS"               "PEON DE\nLOS BAOS"
```

The regex is `^\S+\s+\S+\K\s+` (see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/KAqEaM/1)), it matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespace chars.